# Why I am still getting "Target container is not a DOM element." in ReactDom.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a little game in React.js. The main problem I met is Reactjs ReactDOM.render() method  which every time I run in the browser:

localhost:3000

I am getting:

Target container is not a DOM element.

index.html

```
<div id="game"></div>
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
let x=1;
let y=1;

class Pool extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <div>
        <p>aaa</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
 }


class Board extends React.Component {
func(i,j){
    return <p>dfsdf</p>;    
}
render() {
    return(
        <Pool />
    );
}
}

class Game extends React.Component {
render() {
     return (
      <div>      
        <Board />
      </div>
      );
    }
 }

   ReactDOM.render( <Game />
    ,document.getElementById('game'));
```

Comment: Where is index.js referenced in your html? In the head or the bottom of the DOM?

Comment: Shouldn't it make it automatically when I use  npx create-react-app my-app??

Comment: Can we see `index.html` please?

Comment: There's only one line mentioned above. Few weeks ago I did alittle game and this one line was enough

Comment: My point is that you commonly see this error in react apps (or javascript in general) when the script querying the DOM is in the head of the document. The issue is that when the script is in the head, the script runs before the DOM element exists. Therefore the DOM element does not exist.